# At the time upload files from my website I'm getting this error

Tags: asp.net

I am developing website in ASP.NET Framework in which there is one page where user needs to upload file for registration purpose it should be in pdf format but when i click on submit button i m getting error page.

Below is stack trace

```
Could not find a part of the path 'E:\ASPapps\youth\Resumes\innovation\About Stacks.pdf'.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'E:\ASPapps\youth\Resumes\innovation\About Stacks.pdf'.
```

Source Error:

```
An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
```

Stack Trace:

```
[DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'E:\ASPapps\youth\Resumes\innovation\About Stacks.pdf'.]
   System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath) +224
   System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath) +1142
   System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share) +83
   System.Net.Mail.AttachmentBase.SetContentFromFile(String fileName, String mediaType) +76
   System.Net.Mail.Attachment..ctor(String fileName, String mediaType) +38
   InventeamHP.innovation_Register.SendMail(String emailid, String bccemailid, String body) +715
   InventeamHP.innovation_Register.lbtnESubmit_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) +8078
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton.OnClick(EventArgs e) +118
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +113
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +9
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +176
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +5563
```

Comment: Seems obvious but thought I would ask: does the `E:\ASPapps\youth\Resumes\innovation` folder exist? And if it does exist, does the identity you are running your application under has write permissions to this folder? I assume you are attempting to store the uploaded file inside.

Comment: Well, the error looks pretty clear to me. The path where you're trying to upload the file doesn't exist. Make sure this path exist in your file system

Comment: put your code of upload

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using code like this (I don't know your code):

ASPX:

```
<input id="up" runat="server" type="file" />
```

Code behind:

```
up.PostedFile.SaveAs(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/")+"yourFolder\\"+up.PostedFile.FileName);
```

*and also as  Darin Dimitrov said, make sure that your folder exists.*